# auto-correlation interpretation

Tags: time-series

LM test for autocorrelation up to order 1 -
  Null hypothesis: no autocorrelation
  Test statistic: LMF = 228.871
  with p-value = P(F(1, 62) > 228.871) = 1.75251e-022

how do we interpret this given result, for a time series auto-correlation test?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:

This algorithm performs the **Breusch-Godfrey test** for autocorrelation of order 1. The Null hypothesis here is $$H_0 : \text{No autocorrelation of order p = 1} $$

The **p-values** indicate that **the probability, under the null hypothesis of** (no first order autocorrelation), **of obtaining a result** (i.e. LMF statistic) **equal to or more extreme than what was actually observed** (i.e. $\geq$ 228.871) **is extremely low** (note that the LMF statistic under the null $\sim F(1, 62)$). We may thus say that,  the null hypothesis can be rejected at a reasonable pre-determined significance level. Therefore, you may expect there is first order autocorrelation on your regression residuals.